# write a list of dictionaries into a csv with duplicate headers

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries as:

```
> list_dict=[{gene1:1, gene2:3, gene3:2}, {gene1:3, gene2:1, gene3:4},
> {gene1:2, gene1:1, gene2:1, gene3:3}]
```

I am trying to used the above code:

```
header = dict_list[0].keys()

with open('/path_to_file/mycsv.csv', 'w') as csv_output:
    writer=csv.DictWriter(csv_output,header,delimiter='\t')
    writer.writeheader()
    for samp in dict_list:
        writer.writerow(samp)
```

But when I try it it gives me the following error:

**writer.writeheader() AttributeError: DictWriter instance has no attribute 'writeheader'**

I think that the problem is that sometimes I have a duplicate header as gene1. Could anyone give me some advice on how I can deal with issues please?
I would like that duplicate to appear on the csv either but having that column or having two values for that particular header.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid. I am using python 2.7.